# Flex/as3: How to get the name from a NetStream object?

Tags: apache-flex, netstream

In a Flex [NetStatusEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html) of type `NetGroup.MulticastStream.PublishNotify`, you get the String name of the stream in e.info.name

The name is what the publisher specified in the .publish ("") method.

But in a NetStatusEvent of type `NetStream.Connect.Success`, there is no such property. Instead, the whole [NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html) object is available through `e.info.stream`

How the heck to you get something as basic as the name from the NetStream object? `e.info.stream.name` does not exist.

I must be overlooking something very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as expected, the solution is very simple. The `NetStream.Connect.Success` event fires as soon as the NetStream is initialized. It can be used to .play any published stream - in other words, it has not been assigned a .publish'ed name at this point.